# mysql select statement with where clause and select one row extra

Tags: mysql

I want to do a MySQL select like `SELECT * WHERE number >= 3` but I also want to have the value below the 3 in the results (I don't know if that is 2 or 1).

How can I adjust the query so that this value is also in the results?

Comment: @Kermit No, that's not what the OP is asking.  If I understand, this is to retrieve `> 3`, and additionally the single record that precedes that set, whatever it may be.

Comment: Misread... then `WHERE number > 3 AND number = 3-1`

Comment: It's interesting that rows with `number = 3` are not to be considered at all.

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar does this meet your need?

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not reliably know the value of `number` in the row that precedes the `number >= 3` set, you will need to do a `UNION` between the query you have, and another limited to the first row `< 3`.

```
-- Main query returns the >= 3 set
(
  SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE number >= 3
)
-- Combined with another limited to one record 
-- with a descending sort < 3
UNION (
  SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE number < 3
  ORDER BY number DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
-- If you need a global order on these, apply it here outside the UNION
ORDER BY number ASC
```

Note that I have used `SELECT col1, col2, col3` above. It is generally not advisable to `SELECT *` in production code, but *especially* not in a `UNION` query. It is important to be explicit about the order columns are returned.

Comment: Consider using `UNION ALL`.